# Running TCP and UDP in parallel using OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I would like to use five TCP and five UDP streams (sending and receiving) in parallel on a single host, where the UDP traffic consists of video, and the TCP traffic is arbitrary. How do I use both transport layers in parallel on the same node?

Answer (score 0):

In `INET 3.0.0` there is an example `nclients` in `examples\inet` directory. It could be a good start point to prepare your model.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the TCP and UDP traffic is independent, you can easily install several UDP and TCP applications at the same time in the same host. Something like this:

```
**.cli[*].numTcpApps = 2
**.cli[*].tcpApp[0].typename = "TelnetApp"  
**.cli[*].tcpApp[1].typename = "TCPBasicClientApp"
**.cli[*].numUdpApps = 2
**.cli[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"  
**.cli[*].udpApp[1].typename = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"
// ... further cofiguration of the applications
```

Comment: Thanks allot dear Rudi, I understood..but i am new in omnet++..i could not  make it.. Please send me complete code od udp and tcp based host.  3 to 6 udp based communication (VOIP, video streaming) and 3 to 6 tcp hosts of tcp based...i have to find out only end to end delay and jitter by varying the buffer size of router for udp traffic only..